# Will C++14 support unconstrained generic functions?

Tags: c++, generics, auto, c++14, c++-concepts

While looking at the GCC 4.9.0 release changes [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html), I was pleasantly surprised to read the following; under the "New Languages and Language specific improvements" section for C++:

> G++ supports unconstrained generic functions as specified by §4.1.2
>   and §5.1.1 of [N3889: Concepts Lite Specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3889.pdf). Briefly, auto
>   may be used as a type-specifier in a parameter declaration of any
>   function declarator in order to introduce an implicit function
>   template parameter, akin to generic lambdas.

```
// the following two function declarations are equivalent
auto incr(auto x) { return x++; }
template <typename T>
auto incr(T x) { return x++; }
```

I built GCC 4.9.0 and my initial tests worked as expected. I believe that Concepts Lite will remain somehow auxiliary to the upcoming C++14 specification. Is there though any plan for "unconstrained generic functions" to become a part of C++?

Comment: While I don't think this will become 100% official until C++17, you can almost do it in C++14: `auto incr = [](auto x) {return x++;};`

Comment: Cheers chris. Yes, I'm aware of that one.

Comment: I can not find any of the additions mentioned in `4.1.2` and `5.1.1` of `N3889` in the latest draft standard `N3936` so I would say no for C++14.

Comment: Is it in C++17?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we look at the latest draft standard [N3936](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/tree/b7b8ed08ba4c111ad03e13e8524a1b746cb74ec6/papers) which is pretty close to the C++14 DIS which is `N3937`(*this is covered in [N3938](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3938.html)*). It does not contain any of the language specified in sections `4.1.2` and `5.1.1` of `N3889`.

So for C++14 it looks like the answer is no, but [Bjarne Stroustrup says concepts lite will be a technical report](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#what-concepts). You can find more about technical reports on [ISO cpp's Current Status page](http://isocpp.org/std/status) which says:

> Beyond C++14, the committee contemplates producing another C++
>   Standard in approximately 2017. That doesn’t mean nothing is happening
>   in the meantime, however, because we currently have eight (8) separate
>   Technical Specifications underway, several of which are on track to be
>   published in 2014 and 2015. Starting in 2012, the committee has
>   transitioned to a “decoupled” model where major pieces of work can
>   progress independently from the Standard itself and be delivered as
>   separate TS’s. Vendors can choose to implement these, and the
>   community can gain experience with the std::experimental version of
>   each feature. This lets us learn and adjust each feature’s design
>   based on experience before it is formally included in a future version
>   of the actual C++ Standard